# Android keystore data getting cleared

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have an app that uses AndroidKeystore, and after certain days while reopening the application the Keystore data getting cleared.

Can anybody confirm is there any lifetime or scope of the Keystore?

Answer (score 0):

Goto **File/Project Structure/Modules/Signing Congif**

Here add your keystore path and other detail required in form. The Store Key Alias and Password will be save in build.gradle(app) file.